# How to get a collection of paragraphs from a RichtTextBox in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to code a program for dubbing videos from one language to another. The concept is simple: you just have to mark the beginning and end of a video segment, paste those times in a specific format to the richTextBox, indicating the character that speaks, and put one paragraph of text below, which is to be read by the dubbing actor.

At the end of this process, you also have to count the lines that each actor reads, in order to calculate the payment.

The problem I'm having is I cannot find a way to get a collection of all paragraphs in the RTB. I would need to store each paragraph in a string array in order to format the timecode paragraph in a special way and somehow count the lines of the paragraph below, and do this for all text in the box.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

This is an example of the document:

DUB[N 00:01:24:15>00:02:35:22] ROB
This is the paragraph that the actor must read. It can be any length. Its lines have to be counted and added to calculate the payment.

DUB[N 00:01:24:15>00:02:35:22] MARY
This is the paragraph that the actor must read. It can be any length. Its lines have to be counted and added to calculate the payment.

Comment: please publish your code

Comment: How do you define `"lines"` when you say, *"Its lines have to be counted"*

Comment: About the lines, in the example, both Rob and Mary would have 2 lines each. Of course, the number of lines in each paragraph would be ultimately defined by the left and right margins of the document, but those parameters are already established by the client.

Comment: That does not explain how the lines are calculated. Wouldn't it be easier to just charge a smaller amount per character?

Comment: So far I am in the research stage for this feature. I already have the video part (which I thought was gonna be the most difficult) up and running using QuickTime. I can get both the begin and end times, build the appropriate format and paste in the richTextBox in the proper position. But I have few ideas as to how to count the lines in the paragraph below. The only thing I can think of is splitting the whole contents of the RTB at every newline character, which I assume is "\n" for Windows. Would that be the way to go? Thanks!

Comment: In `C#` it would be `Environment.NewLine`. But if you're reading lines from a document, then it would just be the number of lines after the header (and before the next header, if there is one).

Comment: The client requires a document with very precise formatting for the lines and payment calculation: it has to be in Courier New 14pt, letter size, with 1 inch left and right margins. The method for calculating the payment falls beyond my control. I have to deliver what they need.